# Vertex Paint - Cornering Issue

Tags: materials, displacement, vertex-groups, vertex-colors

I've made a vertex group on the model of edges I want to displace:

[image]

In Vertex Paint mode (Vertex Selection) I selected the vertex group, and then set that full black (Paint > Set Vertex Colors):

[image]

**Overall, this is doing what I need** -- the lines and nice sharp corners marked with green arrows are exactly what I'm going for.  The triangular blob-of-black corners marked with red arrows are what I need to be like the green-arrowed corners.

**Using this as a displacement map for the seams of a patches effect is the goal** -- this shows the green-arrow corners doing what I need, while the red-arrow corners are causing triangular depressions:

[image]

Using a Subdivision modifier thickened / rounded all of it, as did assigning a low Weight to the Vertex group and Paint > Vertex Color from Weight:

[image]

Please note:

1. The pics and blend file attached are an example of the problem, the models this is intended for are larger, with more patches, and a lot more of these corners.  Any answer that requires labor-intensive work on each problem corner won't be a workable solution.
2. Part of the reason I'm using this method (and 3D art in general) is that I have a sheaf of disabilities that make hand-painting difficult for me.  Any variation on “Why don't you just paint . . . ?” won't be a workable solution.
3. Edited to clarify (thanks calambre):  The example model, and the models this is intended for, are "good" all-quads topology and should remain so.  Any answer that requires changing the topology from all-quads, or in ways that can cause other issues (adding poles that can cause shading artifacts, for example) won't be a workable solution.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok then try this, pick those two faces in edit mode, triangulate with Ctrl T and go back to quads with Alt J... seems to work here

in fact you could try the trick with entire mesh selected haha maybe you are lucky

[image]

---

well... this is what seems to have worked the best for KickAir8p:

the idea is to just bevel the edges to be painted -using 2 segments to try to avoid poles-
that helps with the flow of the colored line... here's a pic

[image: bevel with 2 segments]

maybe you can tag the edges and solve the bevel with an extra modifier in your stack?

Comment: Selecting the whole mesh, triangulating it, then tris-to-quads didn't help.  Neither did triangulating the problem corners and then requading them as you showed, but even if that had please see from my Note 1 above, “Any answer that requires labor-intensive work on each problem corner won't be a workable solution.”  But thx!

Comment: ok, I don't fully understand your workflow, maybe it can be changed somewhere else to get similar results... btw if you bevel those selected edges you get strips that may be more stable..? good luck anyway

Comment: just tried the bevel thing, with 2 segments to keep it all quads, and again, using my cube [it looks ok](https://ibb.co/YdkDxj0)

Comment: Yep, beveling as shown in that pic did the job, thx!  There's some distortion of the UV mapping that runs afoul of "changing the topology . . . in ways that can cause other issues", but I think in practice that's gonna be minor.  Put this in an answer and you get the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

Looks that you need to triangulate those faces, in edit mode select those 2 vertices and press 'J', that should do it... I think. Unless the output later is different if you use modifiers...

[image]

Comment: The example model is all-quads topology because the models this is intended for are all-quads (and should remain so).  But Thx!